# webpack.config.js not setting global less variable

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, laravel-mix, less-loader

Any idea of why this `webpack.config.js` is not setting the global `LESS` variable: `current-vehicle` defined on: `/resources/scripts/theme.js`?

**/webpack.config.js**

```
const merge = require("webpack-merge");
const path = require("path");
const baseConfig = require("laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config");

require('dotenv').config();

/**
 * Update the output directory and chunk filenames to work as expected.
 *
 * @param {object} config - The webpack config
 *
 * @return {object} The updated webpack config
 */
const addOutputConfiguration = config => {
  const publicPath = process.env.CDN_URL + '/js/';
  return merge(config, {
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/cdn/js"),
      publicPath,
      chunkFilename: "[name].js"
    },
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          loader: 'less-loader',
          options: {
            modifyVars: require("./resources/scripts/theme")
          }
        },
      ],
    },
  });
};

module.exports = addOutputConfiguration(baseConfig);
```

Here you have the full repo: https://github.com/tlg-265/issue-import-less.local

### Setup

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tlg-265/issue-import-less.local
$ cd issue-import-less.local
$ npm i
$ npm run watch

Then open with the browser (you do NOT need a server).
```

That `LESS` variable: `current-vehicle` is read here:

https://github.com/tlg-265/issue-import-less.local/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/controls/ModalWindow/ModalWindow.less#L1

When you do: `$ npm run watch`, you get the error: `Variable @current-vehicle is undefined`, as you can see on the screenshot below:

[image]

Ideally, when you run it, you should get the following on the browser:

[image]

and when clicking the link, you should get:

[image]

but unfortunatelly I haven't been able to arrive there yet.

Any idea on how to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried it? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075144/import-global-variables-in-less-loader)

Comment: any idea on how can I integrate that into my repo? are you able to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your configuration shocked me:

```js
    module: {
      loaders: [ // <==== !!!!!! here
        {
          loader: 'less-loader',
          options: {
            modifyVars: require("./resources/scripts/theme")
          }
        },
      ],
    },
```

I remember the `loaders` key was for Webpack version 1 or 2, after version 3 they highly recommended use `rules`, please change it to `rules` and try it. I don't know, maybe it comes from Laravel webpack configuration.

Any way, after `less-loader` please add this loader too:

```js
{ 
  loader: 'text-transform-loader',
  options: {
    prependText: '@import "./resources/scripts/theme.less"',
  },
},
```

Comment: the file: `./resources/scripts/theme.less` doen't exist

Comment: based on your suggestion (which I think cotains a small mistake), I tried something similar with no luck: https://i.ibb.co/D7wx0z0/image.png. As you can see 1. I removed previous loader, since that didn't work and I was trying to... 2. use `text-transform-loader` to import the variable value at the beginning of less files, but still getting previous error: `Variable @current-vehicle is undefined`. Bear in mind that variable: `process.env.VEHICLE` is defined on `.env` file (also tried hardcoding its value). Could you maybe try by yourself and post the needed `git-diff` for this to work? Thanks!

Comment: @Viewsonic, For your first comment: man, I just take the `./resources/scripts/theme.less` from your codes in question post. if it doesn't existed, so make it and pass variables init. and test it, it should works.

Comment: @Viewsonic, for your second. if you add some environment variables inside `.env` file and got `undefined` so you should install `dotenv` package and import it in both webpack and root of your project like: `const dotEnv = require('dotenv');` or `import dotEnv from 'dotenv'` then run it by `dotEnv.config();`. after this whole the project can understand environment variables.

Comment: @Viewsonic, Also please do not mix things, the `less-loader` is needed in any cases, because your CSS making is based on using Less. so you should have it. the `text-transform-loader` should be add after `less-loader` object. like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqiGh.png)

Comment: @Viewsonic, try these suggestions and let me know about the result. hope it works, if not inform in here and I will help you with another way.

Comment: @Viewsonic, I'm glad to helped you ❤️, I upvoted your question too.